# .NET 5 can replace .NET Standard where .NET Core 3.1 cannot ? Use case

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-5

In October I was asked to take over an IT project from a colleague who left to another company. This colleague made an IT Project where he had to use "old libraries" written in .NET Framework 4.7 . He wanted to use a WPF application in .NET Core and quickly experienced that he could not immediately reference these .NET Framework 4.7 projects. With setting up the entire architecture as in the picture below, he used .NET Standard 2.0 projects in the Business Logic (where the old libraries are called). These business logic was able to be referenced in the WPF .Net Core 3.1 application on the one hand and call the .NET Framework 4.7 Projects on the other side (in this simplified example: Food Calculator and Shelter Calculator).

When I took over in November, .NET 5 was released and I came across this article [Microsoft Says .Net 5 replaces .NET Standard (Except for...)](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/09/16/net-standard-future.aspx)  . This had me to think that I could maybe go for .NET 5 *all the way* and I ported all code (except for the old libraries that I cannot change for the moment) to .NET 5. Now this seems to work which simplified the architecture I believe.

Please have a look to my overview where the first version (1.0) is in red and the second version (2.0) in blue.

**Now my question:** Is it safe to conclude that in this case, .NET 5 is not just *the next version of .NET Core 3.1* but even took it further... in a way that .NET 5 also made .NET Standard obsolete in these kinds of architectures? Or was this a very particular case and would, if I want to make a Blazor client instead of a WPF, .NET Standard still be needed?

[image: Animal IT Project]

Comment: As long as you haven't ported all your apps to .NET 5, you will still benefit from using .NET Standard in your shared class libraries.

Comment: In which way I will benefit? I am afraid that I will lose performance, and sorry for not mentioning before, but performance is a focus point in the type of project I make for my employer.

Comment: If you have apps that still target .NET Core or .the .NET Framework. .NET 5 still implements .NET Standard so you won't lose any performance when actually running on .NET 5.

Comment: Thank you already for the responses. I have however an extra question: So in this particular use case I described above, you do not see a reason for me to change it back to .NET Standard?

And am I correct if I say that my former colleague (without the availability of .NET 5) could not put the business logic in .NET Core 3.1 as you cannot reference .NET Framework 4.7 than (to call the Food or Shelter Calculator)?

Comment: Have you ported all apps to .NET 5? Then it doesn't really matter. But the only real benefit of upgrading the class libraries from .NET Standard to .NET 5 is that you will be able to use any new API that's not in .NET Standard. As far as performance is concerned, you will still get the performance benefits that .NET 5 brings when running your app on .NET 5, regardless of whether the referenced class libraries are compiled against .NET Standard or .NET 5.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information. I conclude that my current version 2.0 is okay regarding the used frameworks, as I will be able to use new APIs (of .NET 5) if available and that I am already prepared for the time that we (in consulation with my colleagues who also use the Food Calculator in other projects) manage to port the Food Calculator and Shelter Calculator to .NET 5 (or even .NET 6 next year).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 5 and beyond will eventually make .NET Standard obsolete but as long as you haven't ported all your apps to .NET 5, you will still benefit from using .NET Standard in your shared class libraries.

Doing this means that you can reference them from your new .NET 5 apps, as well as from apps that still target .NET Core or the .NET Framework.

The only real benefit of upgrading the class libraries from .NET Standard to .NET 5 is that you will be able to use any new API that's not present in .NET Standard.